# Infinite averages

Tags: infinity, average

If you wanted to find the average of infinite items, what would it be?

Would an estimate of the first x averaged be a good estimate?

Or would the value be nearly zero because you are dividing by infinity?

I mean, basically the summation has to be infinity, but you're also dividing by infinity.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: This is vague.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value

Comment: There _is_ a reasonable definition, but it depends on the order of the elements given. While the definition says the average of $(0,1,0,1,\dots)$ might be $\frac12$, the average of $(0,1,1,0,1,1,\dots)$ — a rearrangement of the previous list — might be $\frac23$. (Though you might be thinking of an uncountable set, like the set of all numbers between $0$ and $1$. That's different than what I've just discussed.)

Comment: But that rearrangement is postponing numbers though, and that's deceptive.
Say you have an arrangement 010101..., in order to convert to 011011, you have to postpone one zero and grab the next one. When you do that for infinity you really end up with two sets, one that equals 2/3 and another that equals -1/6 (000100010001).

Comment: @LeeLouviere I'm not postponing any number _indefinitely_. The zero in position 3, for example, just goes to position 4 in the rearrangement. No individual number has disappeared.

Comment: But then your next subset in the pattern can't start with 11.
You inevitable postpone numbers indefinitely.

010101010101 => 011001100110, not 011011011011

Comment: @LeeLouviere Well… there are some numbers I'm postponing a million places, and some numbers I'm postponing a billion places, but no specific number is being postponed an infinite number of places.

Comment: Try averaging, say, $\{\dots,.001,.01,.1\}\cup\{.9,.99,.999,\dots\}$ in some order, and you'll run into the same problem. You could try alternating between one-y numbers and nine-y numbers, and get an average of $\frac12$ — or try doing one one-y number and two nine-y numbers and repeat, and you'll get an average of $\frac23$. It's the same idea, but this time every number is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm going to assume you mean *arithmetic average*, but the same applies for others too.)

This doesn't generally make any sense for several reasons, mainly because you *can't look up an infinite amount of values* to calculate the average of.

We can take the average of the first $n$ values and let $n$ grow, but this means that the order of the values in this "infinite list" is going to affect the average value you've calculated.

The only way this can work is if 1) We can find some sort of pattern in the values and 2) The value

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n}{n} \to 0$$

Then the average will be zero. An example would be if $x_i = 1/i^3$ for all $i=1,2,3,\dots$

Comment: Yeah, but the problem I'm imagining is if I put the smaller values first, it diverges. But if I put the largest values first it converges. That makes no sense.

Comment: @LeeLouviere How do you mean? In my example above, there are always infinitely many "small" numbers (smaller than some $\epsilon > 0$), so you can't put them first and then something "after".

Comment: I mean if I order the numbers from largest to smallest, it converges, because there are infinitely more smaller numbers than the largest.

But if I order the numbers from smallest to largest, it diverges, because I don't know what the largest number is.

Comment: @LeeLouviere Convergence and limit may depend on summation order, that's not something specific about averages.

Answer (score 4):

You need to endow your infinite set with a *measure* such that the whole space has measure $1$ and then integrate (and hope that your function is measurable to begin with). For finite sets, the obvious choice of measure is the counting measure divided by the number of elements; this gives the usual average. Even weighted averages can be achieved by playing with the measure. However for infinite sets, things are more difficult than just counting ...